# Using Multiple Apps with Google App Indexing

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I am currently working on enabling Google App Indexing (https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi) in my Android app. Our web app however uses two apps, specialized for different use cases. The app I'm working on is the clear preference for which app should open a link from our website on Google Search but what if this one isn't installed and the other one is? Is there a way to open up a different Android app if the first one is not installed? Or does app indexing only associate one app with one link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked our Google contacts about this, their answer was: At the moment it is only possible to connect one app to your website. You have to decide which one you prefer.